# QuickSort void problems

Tags: c#, quicksort

I've been trying to write my own quicksort in C#.

However, when I concatenate the lower, pivot and greater partitions, Visual Studio tells me it cant convert void to string list, though I'm not sure how the concatenated lessList and moreList even becomes void.

Code snippet:

```
    public List<string> SortFiles(List<string> fileList)
    {
        int listSize = fileList.Count;

        if (listSize <= 1)
        {
            return fileList; //because it is already sorted
        }

        string pivotString = fileList[listSize/2];

        //partition list
        List<string> lessList = new List<string>();
        List<string> moreList = new List<string>();

        foreach (string g in fileList)
        {
            if (String.Compare(g, pivotString) <= 0)
            {
                lessList.Add(g);
            }
            else
            {
                moreList.Add(g);
            }
        }

        lessList = SortFiles(lessList);
        moreList = SortFiles(moreList);

        //concatenate lessList + pivot + moreList
        List<string> sortedFiles = lessList.Add(pivotString); //thinks is void
        sortedFiles = sortedFiles.AddRange(moreList);         //thinks is void

        return sortedFiles;
```

Comment: `Add` and `AddRange` return `void`. What exactly is the compiler supposed to do?

Comment: You mean: 
lessList.Add(pivotString);
sortedFiles = lessList;
sortedFiles.AddRange(moreList);

Answer (score 2):

The fact is that `Add` and `AddRange` don't return a new list with the added element (or range).
Rather, they add the element(s) to the list, modifying it in-place.

In fact you can simply modify the code to just do the `Add` and `AddRange`, and it will work.

Note though that it will be rather inefficient, as you are creating lists and copying thing around a lot.